# NoMethodError, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Hello I can not understand what the cause of the error when searching the Sphinx.
Controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
 def show
   @results = Search.get_results(params[:query], params[:context])
 end
end
```

Model:

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
  CONTEXTS = ['Questions', 'Answers', 'Comments', 'Users']

  def get_results(query, context)
   query = ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(query)
   klasses = [context.singularize.constantize] if CONTEXTS.include?(context)
   @results = ThinkingSphinx.search(query, classes: klasses, order: 'model_order ASC') if query.present?
  end
 end
```

Error: NoMethodError in SearchesController#show,

```
undefined method `get_results' for Search(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class
```

when used in self in the method

```
def self.get_results(query, context)
# ...
end
```

the error will be: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass in string

```
query = ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(query)
```

I am a beginner ... but I can not understand .. maybe sphinx installed incorrectly

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you know that you are not showing us where you are using the `gsub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different bugs.

The first one is that you are defining an instance method, but using it on the class (instead of on an instance). A class method starts `self` eg

```
def self.my_method_name
```

and can be called on the main class eg `Search.my_method_name` instead of a specific instance of the search class. An example of calling an instance method with the same name would be:

```
my_search = Search.new(:some => :attributes)
my_search.my_method_name
```

SO, your first error message tells you "there is no method called `get_results` on the `Search` class" - and this is because you have defined it as `def get_results` instead of `def self.get_results`

So, then you tried adding `self.` and this error went away.

This then exposed the next bug - which is completely unrelated to the first one.

The second error complains that you are calling `gsub` on nil.

the `gsub` is probably something happening inside of the `ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(query)` call.

and you can't (easily) change anything inside of another library... but you can still glean useful information from the error message.
In this case, the error is complaining that you're calling a method on `nil`... that means that something is `nil` that it was expecting to be not-nil.

Given this is a search-query thing... my best guess would be that it is assuming that the `query` variable is some kind of string... containing a search-query.

It probably is expecting that query * NOT * to be a nil.

and yet in this instance it is.

What if...

a) somebody hits the "go" button without entering a search-query?

b) you accidentally made a typo in the parameter name in your form and so nothing is actually coming through for `params[:query]` ?

c) the nesting of your params is slightly different to what you expect (eg `params[:search_form][:query]`)

Firstly - you should double-check that your forms are sending through the `params` that your controller actually expects. You can do this by looking in the logs -> either in the terminal/console window, or in your logfiles (usually `log/development.log`) and watching what happens when you hit the submit-button on your search form. The logs will list the parameters that come through when you submit that form and you can double-check it's exactly what you expect.

Secondly: you probably should not actually do the searching if no query comes through - people will accidentally hit the submit button even when they haven't typed something - and it'd be a nicer GUI if your app didn't explode when that happens :)

You could do something like this:

```
def self.get_results(query, context)
  return nil unless query.present?
  # ... the rest of the method here
end
```

Just make sure that your view explicitly checks for nil and doesn't explode in that case.